# Algebraic data types in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, algebraic-data-types

**Worded an other way**:

How would you type the `windowState` DOM property in TypeScript?

***SOLVED*** (in TypeScript 2):

```
declare var windowState: WindowState
const enum WindowState {
  STATE_MAXIMIZED = 1,
  STATE_MINIMIZED = 2,
  STATE_NORMAL = 3,
  STATE_FULLSCREEN = 4
}
...
var windowState = 5 // Type Error, as expected!
```

**Original question**:

How do I `declare` a `type` in TypeScript so that it describes an algebraic data type? The purpose of this is describing an existing API.

When I try the following, TypeScript obviously complains that a *`type is expected`*:

```
type Weather = 'sunny' | 'bad'
```

One idea I had is using a JavaScript 2015 `Symbol`, however TypeScript doesn't seem to know about these.

An other idea was using an `enum`, however TypeScript complains that a *`member initializer must be constant expression`*:

```
const enum Weather {
  sunny = 'sunny',
  bad = 'bad',
  windy = Symbol('windy')
}
```

I would have thought that a `string` constant is a constant expression.

Comment: For this particular example, you could probably use an `enum` (need to convert to/from String in places, though)

Comment: Yes, I'll add that to the question as well, as an `enum` was not really satisfactory

Comment: TypeScript does understand Symbols.  If your runtime environment supports it, you can either load the `lib.es6.d.ts` or you can replicate the Symbol interface.

Comment: @Kitson Does it regard them as a constant expression, though?

Comment: @CodeiSir And `Symbol`s?

Comment: TypeScript 1.8 will introduce "String Literal Types": https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/5185

Comment: Awesome, that's not full algebraic data type support, but exactly what I need for my purpose. Thank you. Why not turn your comment into an answer?

Comment: You haskell snippet is incorrect. The rhs of a data declaration should contain *value constructors* not values.

Comment: @pedrofurla Ok sorry, what would be the correct way to express this type in Haskell?

Comment: `data Weather = Sunny | Bad`

Comment: has it become more natural to work with algebraic data types since years ago?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

TypeScript 2.0 has support for discriminated unions/algebraic data types. The documentation is [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#discriminated-unions).

> You can combine string literal types, union types, type guards, and type aliases to build an advanced pattern called *discriminated unions*, also known as *tagged unions* or *algebraic data types*.
>   Discriminated unions are useful in functional programming.
>   Some languages automatically discriminate unions for you; TypeScript instead builds on JavaScript patterns as they exist today.
>   There are three ingredients:
>
> 1. Types that have a common literal (or enum) property — the *discriminant*.
> 2. A type alias that takes the union of those types — the *union*.
> 3. Type guards on the common property.

Let's start:

```
interface Square {
    kind: "square";
    size: number;
}
interface Rectangle {
    kind: "rectangle";
    width: number;
    height: number;
}
interface Circle {
    kind: "circle";
    radius: number;
}
```

> First we declare the interfaces we will union.
>   Each interface has a `kind` property with a different string literal type.
>   The `kind` property is called the *discriminant* or *tag*.
>   The other properties are specific to each interface.
>   Notice that the interfaces are currently unrelated.
>   Let's put them into a union:

```
type Shape = Square | Rectangle | Circle;
```

> Now let's use the discriminated union:

```
function area(s: Shape) {
    switch (s.kind) {
        case "square": return s.size * s.size;
        case "rectangle": return s.height * s.width;
        case "circle": return Math.PI * s.radius ** 2;
    }
}
```

In each of those branches, TypeScript will narrow down the type.
If you try to use a `case` clause with a value that isn't present as any `kind` property, then TypeScript will error.

Comment: Can you give an example how to call such a function with a literal argument of that type? I guess I'm confused by false analogies to the Haskell syntax.

Answer (score 4):

To use enum's you would write it something [like this](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=enum%20Weather%20%7B%0A%09Sunny%2C%0A%09Windy%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Alet%20currently%20%3D%20Weather.Sunny%3B%0A):

```
enum Weather {
    Sunny,
    Windy
};

let currently = Weather.Sunny;
```

### String Literals

The other way the OP is asking for this to be solved are arriving in [TypeScript 1.8](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/5185).

They would allow you to do something like this:

```
type Weather = 'Sunny' | 'Windy';
```

Comment: But I need a `type` that can describe being one of several `string` constants.

Comment: why do you need string constants?

Comment: There is an existing API and this would be a typing for it,

Comment: What you are asking for is coming in TypeScript 1.8 (which is currently available for testing via `npm install typescript@next`